# Magento 1 and /errors folder permissions?

Tags: magento-1.7

I noticed that **/errors** folder is accessible via the web. The folder contains:

404.php

503.php

process.php

reportor.php

Should this folder remain open or better restrict access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my understanding of the /errors folder:

It is completely separated from the base Magento application, so it doesn't need to have restricted access.

Only `php` files aren't restricted in this folder, but `xml` and `phtml` are.

You should be able to freely restrict access to it with the .htaccess inside /errors, just change

```
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|phtml)$">
```

to

```
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|phtml|php)$">
```

But I don't see a reason to do it.